# Angular 2 how do I use a variable for the value of ngClass

Tags: angular, ng-class

I want to use a variable for the value of `ngClass` that will be added to the class list. My use case is that I have a collection of image sprites, there is the base sprite and then an active state which has the same filename as the base sprite only with `-active` added to the end. I add the sprites to the document by giving an element a class matching the desired sprites file name. I need to toggle back and forth between the two sprites when a user hovers over the element. How do I do that?

For example something like this (NOTE: tool.name === the file name of the sprite to display):

```
<li *ngFor='let tool of tools' (mouseenter)='tool.isActive = true' (mouseleave)='tool.isActive = false'>
  <span [ngClass]='{ {{tool.name}}-active: tool.isActive, {{tool.name}}: !tool.isActive }'>{{tool.name}}</span>
</li>
```

Comment: do you need something like toggle isActive between true/false dynamically?

Comment: No, each tool.name matches the filename of a sprite, in addition each sprite has a second file with the same name but -active added. I need to toggle between the two sprites on hover.

Answer (score 6):

In stead of having class `.tool-name-active`
You can have your class as `.tool-name.active`
Then you can do the following

```
<li *ngFor='let tool of tools'>
  <span class="{{tool.name}}" [ngClass]='{active: isActive}'>{{tool.name}}</span>
</li>
```

Comment: .<tool-name>-active is a sprite name so I need the whole string. For example it ends up being .color-btn if isActive is false and .color-btn-active if isActive is true. .color-btn.active would just load the sprite named color-btn.

Comment: I meant you could change your css class name from .color-btn-active to .color-btn.active if it's possible.

Comment: It's not, as I said I need the class to be .color-btn-active so that it matches color-btn-active.png I also need .color-btn so that it matched color-btn.png. If I don't have these classes matching the file names then the sprites don't load.

Comment: But as the way you said, try the solution form The FORCE JB, it might works for you but not recommended.
Other ways are:
1. Renames your stripe to color-btn.active.png
2. If you use css to load the stripe, post your css help and we can help to adjust it.

Comment: Nice answer; you could though easily rewrite: `class="{{tool.name}}"` to `[class]="tool.name"`.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe using a function to return the ngClass array will helps.

```
<li *ngFor='let tool of tools'><span [ngClass]='chkClass(tool)'>{{tool.name}}</span></li>


public chkClass(item:any){
    let newClass = {};
     newClass[item.name+ '-active'] = true;
     newClass[item.name] = false;
     return newClass;
}
```

Comment: Note: function calls in template are bad for performance and against Angular best practice. I would strongly discourage this solution since there are more proper solutions out there to solve this simple use case.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to get `.tool-name-active` | `.tool-name` in one attribute would be:

```
<li *ngFor='let tool of tools'>
  <span [class]="tool.name + (tool.isActive ? '-active' : '')">{{tool.name}}</span>
</li>
```

Or to get the following `.tool-name.active` | `.tool-name` you could also do:

```
<li *ngFor='let tool of tools'>
  <span [class]="tool.name" [class.active]="tool.isActive">{{tool.name}}</span>
</li>
```

See for more information on Angular class binding [the official docs here](https://angular.io/guide/class-binding).